# Swift protocol on class instance never fires

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a swift protocol, but it never fires.

I have 1 class which is an instance, and the other is a class where I want to manage an object;

```
protocol TurnDelegate: class {
    func turnIsCompleted()
}

class ClassOne : NSObject {

    weak var delegate: TurnDelegate?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        delegate?.turnIsCompleted()
    }

}

class ClassTwo: NSObject, TurnDelegate {

    static var instance = ClassTwo()

    func turnIsCompleted() {
        print ("Turn is completed")
    }

}

let c2:ClassTwo = ClassTwo.instance
let c1:ClassOne = ClassOne.init()
```

My issue is that the protocol never fires and does not output "turn is completed"

How can I resolve this?

Edit: How do I set the delegate?

Many thanks

Comment: Because delegate is nil

Comment: Where are you setting ClassOne's delegate to be ClassTwo?

Comment: This cannot work. You have to **set** the delegate.

Comment: I'm aware delegate is nil as I don't know how to set class one delegate.

Comment: Offtop: Person is trying to learn delegates stop downvote.

Comment: The example is not meaningful because in practice you won't call a delegate method in an init method

Comment: @vadian you are right but we should help person to understand how he could handle his case. And than point out that it is a bit bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have describe create custom `init`.

```
class ClassOne : NSObject {

    weak var delegate: TurnDelegate?

    init(with delegate: TurnDelegate?) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        delegate?.turnIsCompleted()
    }

}
```

Than:

```
let c2:ClassTwo = ClassTwo.instance
let c1:ClassOne = ClassOne.init(with: c2)
```

Output:

```
Turn is completed
```

Comment: Okay, I will give it a go

Comment: This works, many thanks.  I will try to play with it more so I understand what is going on a bit more.  My query is resolved.  Thanks

Comment: @cardigan tale a look at vadian answer he wrote how it should be done.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set the delegate.

Usually the delegate is set in an `init` method. The method in the protocol is called later in another method for example

```
protocol TurnDelegate: class {
    func turnIsCompleted()
}

class ClassOne : NSObject {

    weak var delegate: TurnDelegate?

    init(delegate: TurnDelegate?) {
       self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func turnSomething()
    {
        delegate?.turnIsCompleted()
    }

}

class ClassTwo: NSObject, TurnDelegate {

    static let instance = ClassTwo()

    func turnIsCompleted() {
        print ("Turn is completed")
    }

}

let c2 = ClassTwo.instance
let c1 = ClassOne(delegate: c2)
c1.turnSomething()
```

---

However for this purpose especially in conjunction with a singleton I'd prefer a callback closure rather than protocol / delegate. The benefit is less overhead and the callback is directly connected to the calling method.

```
class ClassOne : NSObject {

    func turnSomething()
    {
        let c2 = ClassTwo.instance
        c2.turn { 
            print ("Turn is completed")
        }
    }
}

class ClassTwo: NSObject {

    static let instance = ClassTwo()

    func turn(completion: ()->()) {
        // do heavy work
        completion()
    }

}

let c1 = ClassOne()
c1.turnSomething()
```

Comment: This is good to learn from, and am grateful for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Delegates in all their glory *do* have their drawbacks too. One of them is that relationships between objects and their delegates have to be established explicitly. In Cocoa there are typically two ways of doing this. One is connecting a `delegate` `IBOutlet` in InterfaceBuilder, the other is doing it programmatically. As @OlegGordiichuck points out you could do it in the initializer, but generally in Cocoa delegates tend to be properties. In your case this would boil down to instantiate objects of `ClassTwo` and `ClassOne` and then manually set the delegate of `c2` as in

```
c2.delegate = c1
```

This however defeats your notification mechanism and you would have to have a separate method for notifying the delegate (Which is again typical, as usually your delegate cannot know about is *significant other* during its construction. Moreover the construction of the originator is usually not something the delegate would have to know about).

Comment: I am hoping to use a delegate to notify a turn order manager when a turn is completed, then the turn order manager can make a decision on whether to go to the next player or finish the round (as all players have completed their turns) and I wanted it to be abstracted away from the view controller as I feel the turn order manager should deal with everything to do with turns and turn management.

Comment: This ... does not really show well in your code. Depending on the exact "thing" you want to do it might or might not be appropriate to use a delegate. However, I would assume if it is the *generation* of an object you are interested in, then the solution would rather be a `Strategy` passed through a class variable than a `delegate` passed to each construction call.

Comment: Understood, but for now I just wanted to learn delegates implementation first and work out if thats the best solution for me.